# Packer Docker builder using chmod on Windows 10

Tags: windows, docker, packer

Here is my packer file:

```
    {
        "builders": [{
            "type": "docker",
            "image": "ubuntu",
            "export_path": "image.tar"
        }],
        "provisioners": [{
            "type": "shell",
            "inline": ["mkdir /full_install",
            "mkdir /scripts"]
        },
        {
            "type": "file",
            "source": "./scripts/",
            "destination": "/scripts"
        }]
    }
```

Simple. Trying to just make 2 directories and then upload some scripts to one of the directories. I am getting the following output on Windows 10:

> C:\Work\Packer\myPacker>packer build myServer.json
>    docker output will be in this color.
>
> ==> docker: Creating a temporary directory for sharing data...
>    ==> docker: Pulling Docker image: ubuntu
>        docker: Using default tag: latest
>        docker: latest: Pulling from library/ubuntu
>        docker: Digest: sha256:dd7808d8792c9841d0b460122f1acf0a2dd1f56404f8d1e56298048885e45535
>        docker: Status: Image is up to date for ubuntu:latest
>    ==> docker: Starting docker container...
>        docker: Run command: docker run -v C:\Users\syarnell\AppData\Roaming\packer.d\tmp\packer-docker346952011:/packer-files -d -i -t ubuntu /bin/bash
>        docker: Container ID: 84a0969874bbfc031f60ad03c8e6765f895733cdfd51c727ae59c82a80c82658
>    ==> docker: Provisioning with shell script: C:\Users\syarnell\AppData\Local\Temp\packer-shell141617915
>    ==> docker: Uploading ./scripts/ => /scripts
>    ==> docker: Killing the container: 84a0969874bbfc031f60ad03c8e6765f895733cdfd51c727ae59c82a80c82658
>    Build 'docker' errored: chmod C:\Users\syarnell\AppData\Roaming\packer.d\tmp\packer-docker346952011\dirupload432828853\batchInstall.sh: not supported by windows
>
> ==> Some builds didn't complete successfully and had errors:
>    --> docker: chmod C:\Users\syarnell\AppData\Roaming\packer.d\tmp\packer-docker346952011\dirupload432828853\batchInstall.sh: not supported by windows
>
> ==> Builds finished but no artifacts were created.
>
> C:\Work\Packer\myPacker>

Why is this trying to chmod a file in Windows 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Packer Docker builder doesn't work on Windows, open an issue on github.com.